# OpenStreetMap export

Tags: export, import

When I try to export from OpenStreetMap.org I get a file in this format: map.osm.xml and blender requires that the file to be a .osm file. I've tried just removing the .xml but it doesn't work. In Wiki it says thi "The XML data can be saved to a .osm file and filtered." Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: This question already has an anwser [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173186/where-to-download-osm-files-and-how-to-convert-it-to-xml).

Comment: Sorry, not quite. I don't want to use Geofabrik and I don't want to convert .osm to .xml. I want to use OpenStreetMap and convert and filter the map.osm.xml file it outputs so blender will import the map.osm file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently exporting .osm file from there and everything was fine. Here are steps I made and what was it's outcome:[image: first click]

[image: second click]

Comment: Those are the steps I use, but I don't get the pop up screen that you get titled "Opening map.osm." And I notice you are using Firefox as your browser. Are you using a PC or Mac product? I use Safari. Could that be the problem?

Comment: My PC runs on Ubuntu and Yes, it's Firefox. Maybe You should try Firefox too. At this moment I have no idea what can cause the difference in file extension so probably it's worth trying.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I ran firefox and it worked fine. :0